# How to strategize a slow data generation step of automation framework?

Tags: api, automation, software-testing

I have a sample website I am working with, where you can create an appointment using UI elements. Also, the same appointment can be created using API calls (Chaining endpoints). Another way (which I don't prefer) is directly inserting data on the database.

All these 3 data creation ways take a long time (4-5 minutes). I have a Selenium based automation framework which needs test data, but I am looking for recommendations (tools, libraries, strategy) on how to solve this issue.

What libraries, tools or any suggestion you have to create data so that I can use them as part of my testing in my Selenium framework?